# What cable should I use to display computers image on TV

Tags: dvi, vga, s-video, rca

I have a pretty old computer and [TV](http://pastebin.com/Nh1HsJ6r) (specs on link). I'd like to display the computers image on my TV's screen. My graphic card has **S-Video**, **DVI** and **VGA** output.

The TV's resolution is 1366x768 and has the following inputs:
*Input/Output: AV1:AV In, TV Out, RGB In, AV2:AV In/Out, S-Video In, Q-Link AV4: AV In/out, s-video+RGB in, Q-Link, AV3 (front): RCA AV in, 4pin **S-Video** In*

I don't have to worry about outputting the sound through the TV since my computer already are connected to a pair of speakers.

My question is now: what's the best way to connect these two? S-Video might be an obvious choice - but I read somewhere that the max  resolution was limited to approximately 800x400?

I'm highly appreciating all answers - I'm everything but an expert within this area. Sorry if it's placed in the wrong SE section.

Comment: You're never going to get the full resolution with this TV anyway, so you might as well use an S-Video cable. Only digital connection (or at least a TV with a VGA connector) would be better.

Comment: Since the cables won't let me use the tv's full resolution, what will happend to the image? Will it stretch or just go black for the unfilled pixels?

Comment: It'll probably be stretched and look a bit blurry, but that really depends on your TV.

Comment: I don't really get it, what am I supposed to do with the tv then? Aren't DVD format bigger than 800x400? Makes no sense, might be me who's stupid though :).

Comment: Well, the TV *is* capable of showing the resolution. I think you'll just have to look whether your graphics card can produce the same resolution for your S-Video output. I *think* that should be feasible.

Comment: Although thinking about it I'm not so sure again. Just buy an S-Video cable and see what you can achieve. You don't have many options aside from that.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll give it a try and report back :-). Thanks a LOT for the help, really appreciate it mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any benefit from using this instead of S-Video at both ends?

Transfer of data will take place and the speed of the slowest medium. So even if RCA has quality benefits over S-Video you won't gain them.

However there's no line to carry audio on S-Video for example, where as RCA has an input for it. So I believe if you did S-Video/S-Video you'd be unable to send audio to your TV speakers.

Comment: Makes sense. I won't be using the tv speakers anyway, sound will be coming from the computer.

Comment: Since the cables won't let me use the tv's full resolution, what will happend to the image? Will it stretch or just go black for the unfilled pixels?

Comment: In a nutshell... If you have more pixels in the same amount of space the pixels have to be smaller to fit on the screen, which results in your picture appearing smaller but allowing you to fit more detail onto the screen.

You're computer and TV will BOTH have settings to deal with this.

First, make sure you have the correct Aspect Ratio set on your TV (or as good as possible), if the screen is too big or too small to fit the screen perfectly you can then adjust it with the overscan/underscan settings on your computers graphics/display settings. (like the nVida/ATI control centre)

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks a lot for the help dude, greatly appreciated!

Comment: S-video is a *video* signal, not a computer monitor (i.e. VGA) signal.  There is no pixel count or resolution that you can specify for an S-video signal.  If the PC's graphic card outputs an S-video signal, then that means the PC's main display (at whatever resolution) is scanned and converted to a proper S-video signal (which happens to be luminance and chrominance for 525-line NTSC).

Comment: *"So even if RCA has quality benefits over S-Video"* : **RCA** in this content is just a type of connector; there is no "RCA signal".  RCA connectors are used for analog audio, digital audio, composite video and component video on TVs.  **S-video** is a signal type, and also the common name for the 4-pin DIN connector used for that signal.  Comparing "RCA" to "s-video" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was under the impression that the RCA connectors allowed for more throughput, not just splitting the pins into individual inputs. +1 for good information, with logical basis